# How to solve there are no such file or directory

Tags: arduino

Heere is the error message

Arduino: 1.8.15 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

In file included from C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\RTC_dan_lcd\RTC_dan_lcd.ino:2:0:

C:\Users\m\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master/DHT_U.h:36:10: fatal error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory

#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

```
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: Check if that file exists locally on your C-Drive at the specified address.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing dependencies and the compiler can't compile. The answer can be found here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53461/i-have-downloaded-the-library-but-not-sure-what-went-wrong/53463